# How to get gradients from scipy.optimize.least_squares for each iteration?

Tags: python, scipy, callback, gradient, least-squares

Im working with a package that uses `scipy.optimize.least_squares` and offers the possibility to use a callback function. However, only objective function parameters are passed to the callback function (for each function evaluation).
I need to get the gradient of the function with respect to the parameters, though. I know that `scipy.optimize.least_squares` computes the gradients for each evaluation via `J.T.dot(f)`, where `J` is the Jacobian and `f` is the function. But the gradient is only returned, after the optimization is finished, via the results and shows the gradient for the last iteration / evaluation (solution).
Is there a way to get the gradient of the cost function with respect to the parameters for each evaluation?